# Alarm keeps playing after onPause called

Tags: java, android

Here's code for a timer that plays a sound once it reaches 0 (timer works fine). The problem is the sound persists even through `onPause()` in `MainActivity.java` called.

I implemented `onDestroy()` in `SimpleIntentService.java` to stop the sound, but apparently it's never called even with `finish()` in the calling `Activity`. How am I supposed to make the sound stop when the app is paused?

Here's my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    NumberPicker picker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        picker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(minutePicker);

        Log.i("TurnToTech", "Project Name - SimpleBackgroundService");

        picker.setMinValue(0);
        picker.setMaxValue(20);

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
                   String text = intent.getStringExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_OUT_MSG);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
    }

    Intent msgIntent;

    public void startTimer(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        msgIntent = new Intent(this, SimpleIntentService.class);
        msgIntent.putExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_IN_MSG, "Alarm: ");
        msgIntent.putExtra("time", picker.getValue());

        startService(msgIntent);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SimpleIntentService.ACTION_RESP);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,filter);
      }

      public void onPause() {
          finish();
          unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
          super.onPause();
      }
}
```

And the `SimpleIntentService.java`

```
public class SimpleIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String PARAM_IN_MSG = "in_msg";
    public static final String PARAM_OUT_MSG = "out_msg";
    int time;

    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "org.turntotech.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

    public SimpleIntentService() {
        super("SimpleIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("SimpleIntentService Called");
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_MSG);
        int time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 0);

        // Timer implementation
        if (time == 0 ){
            playSound();
        }

        while(time > 0){

            SystemClock.sleep(5000); // 5 seconds
            time -= 5;
            String resultTxt = msg + time + " seconds remaining";
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

            broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_RESP);
            broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, resultTxt);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("time", time);

            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            if (time == 0) {
                playSound();
            }
        }
    }

    Uri alert;

    public void playSound(){
        alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alert);
        r.play();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alert);
        r.stop();

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `IntentService` you're not really stopping the same alarm in your `onDestroy` function. Because each time you're getting a new instance of it.

So I would like to suggest to keep a public static variable of `Ringtone` so that it can be accessed from everywhere. Declare them in your `MainActivity`.

```
public static Ringtone r; 
public static Uri alert;
```

Initialize them in the `onCreate` function of your `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ... Other statements 

    // Initialize ringtone here
    initializeRingtone();
}

private void initializeRingtone() {
    alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alert);
}
```

Now the `onPause()` function of your `MainActivity` should look like this

```
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    r.stop();
    super.onPause();
}
```

And if you want to play the sound after you resume the application from background and then the timer runs out, you might consider doing something like this in the `onResume` function of your `MainActivity`

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    initializeRingtone();  // Initialize it again. 
}
```

And the `playSound()` function in the `IntentService` might look like this.

```
public void playSound(){
    // Initialize the alert and ringtone again. 
    MainActivity.alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    MainActivity.r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alert);

    MainActivity.r.play();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    MainActivity.r.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much, but unfortunately the sound doesn't start playing when implemented this way. Just dead silence after timer runs out, any idea why?

Comment: What's the actual scenario here? You took the application in background and the timer stopped playing right? Then again, you resumed the application and you expect the sound should play after the timer runs out?

Comment: That problem was onDestroy() was destroying right after sound was played, so it only played for like a milisecond